# Too big clock skew error in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Getting this error in YugabyteDB cluster:

```
F0531 17:26:15.079571 129854 hybrid_clock.cc:177] Too big clock skew is detected: 0.920s, while max allowed is: 0.900s; clock_skew_force_crash_bound_usec=60000000
```

I am adjusting the `--max_clock_skew_usec` parameter on my TServer config. But I would also like to know where the `clock_skew_force_crash_bound_usec` is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of YugabyteDB’s innovations is not to require highly specialized synchronized clocks among the cluster nodes.

However, we do require time to be "reasonably" synchronized, which still is the key fact to keep the data on nodes synchronized and consistent.

This error means the clocks have drifted too far apart, and thus cannot reasonably be used.
It is vitally important to make sure all your nodes are synchronized to network clock sources using public available methods such as `ntp` or `chrony`. Once these methods have reasonably adjusted the system clocks, the clock skew errors should go away.

Simply adjusting the clock skew threshold is in almost any case not a solution.

It's absolutely required to have clock synchronization with distributed databases: https://blog.yugabyte.com/evolving-clock-sync-for-distributed-databases/